# Cannot convert value of type 'Result<T>' to expected argument type 'Result<_>'

Tags: swift, alamofire, codable

I'm newbie to swift and trying to use this [APIClient](https://github.com/AladinWay/NetworkingExample/blob/master/Networking/APIClient/APIClient.swift) but get that error in completion(response.result) on swift 4.2

```
@discardableResult
private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (Result<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {
    return AF.request(route)
                    .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                        completion(response.result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use typealiases available in AF5. For exmaple:

```
@discardableResult
private static func performRequest<T: Decodable>(route: ApiRouterAuth, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (AFResult<T>) -> Void) -> DataRequest {
    return AF.request(route)
        .responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
            completion(response.result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire 5 does not support Swift 4.2, only Swift 5 and above. Either downgrade to Alamofire v4, or update your completion handler to use `Result<T, Error>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the letters AF in front of Result and DataRequest, it works for me.